# Dynamics 365 (CRM) Online & connecting with XrmToolBox

Tags: dynamics-crm, connection-string, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, xrmtoolbox

I am using...

- XrmToolBox version 1.2017.7.18
- Dynamics 365 Online (login is with user@org.onmicrosoft.com)

I try to create a new connection.

I enter http://orgname.crm.dynamics.com for the Organization url.

then my user / pass

I get this error.

[image]

Then, I try...

using a connection string.

I click the link *"Let me try to connect using a connection string"*

I have tried many connection strings but the one that I think to be correct is listed below.

org is an example name for my Org Name

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Crm" connectionString="Url=https://org.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@org.onmicrosoft.com; Password=mypass; AuthType=Office365" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I try to connect I get the following error.

[image]

I am not sure why I am getting these errors.

Comment: try https://org.crm4.dynamics.com or Path to the organization service `XRMServices/2011/organizationservice.svc`

Comment: org.crm4.dynamics.com gives the same error as the first screen shot other than the url is crm4 vs crm.  I tried the org.api.crm.dynamics.com url, it fails too.

Comment: have you tried `org.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/organizationservice.svc`?

Comment: I'm working on a 8.2 CRM online org right now with that exact version of the toolbox and I have no issues whatsoever, enter org url, username, password, done. Your toolbox is probably messed up (try redownloading) or you've been given the wrong connection details (access crm and check developer resources to verify them)

Comment: org.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/organizationservice.s‌​vc gives me a different error.  I get the message "Unable to login to Dynamics CRM"  I retested my user / pass and I tried the domain name as empty and then with org.onmicrosoft.com.  Same error on both.

Comment: I also downloaded XrmToolBox and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Sometimes when i have that problem I have tried using the <uniquename>.crm.dynamics.org

Comment: Still working on this.  I was able to get the plugin registration tool to connect.  I think this may be related to a dll version or something.  I will keep this updated as I work through the problem.

Comment: Why it is appending sdkversion=8.2 or 9 ?

Answer (score 3):

I too faced same issue. When I try to connect with latest version of **XRM toolbox(1.2018.3.21)**, it's **connected successfully**. You too try with this version and regarding connection using connection string we should not supposed to use as you specified.We just need to **specify the connection string content only**.For example as follows

**Url=https://org.crm.dynamics.com; Username=user@org.onmicrosoft.com; Password=mypass; AuthType=Office365**